# Test of Modality for Frequency Table in R?

Tags: r, gis, distribution, shapefile, elevation

I have created a frequency table of elevation versus area (m^2) from a shapefile in r in the basic format:

`elevation_frequencies <- data.table(elevation = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), area = c(65, 345, 876, 9834, 4, 3487, 987))`

I want to calculate a number of statistics on this distribution of areas across elevations (i.e. modality, skew, mean). However, all of these statistics are typically applied to the raw data rather than the frequency table. Because I extracted this frequency table from a shapefile, I don't have raw data. I could generate raw data by creating a vector where each elevation is repeated by the corresponding value in the area column, however, many area values in my real data are 1,000,000s of kms, and therefore this would exhaust my memory.

Is there a way to directly apply statistics (i.e. modality (diptest?), skew, mean, etc.) to a frequency table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the corresponding formula, following the next pattern you will be able achieve your goal:

In statistic mean of x is equal to sum(x)/length(x) then:

sum(x) is iqual to sum of 0 (65 times) + 1 (345 times), and so on. That is, 0*65 + 1*345 + ... + 6*987

length of x is 65 (0's) + 345 (1's) and so on. That is 65 + 345 + ... + 987

This way:

```r
(elevation_frequencies <- data.frame(elevation = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), area = c(65, 345, 876, 9834, 4, 3487, 987)))

(mean = sum(elevation_frequencies$elevation * elevation_frequencies$area)/sum(elevation_frequencies$area))
```

```
[1] 3.524298
```

```r
(mode = elevation_frequencies$elevation[elevation_frequencies$area == max(elevation_frequencies)])
```

```
3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is not feasible because many of my area values are in the magnitude of millions of kilometers. These types of calculations exhaust the memory on my system. That is why I'm hoping to calculate these statistics directly from the frequency table.

Comment: But, i am using the frequency table. Look the above code carefully.

Comment: I have found a package (equate) that will calculate mean, mode, and median, but I still am in need of a way to calculate modality from the frequency table.